# How can I differentiate ASP elements in Dreamweaver CC 2015?

Tags: asp.net, .net, dreamweaver

I need to work with ASP.NET templates in Dreamweaver CC, but is very annoying that asp elements have the same colors as HTML elements, making very hard to identify dynamic content in a bunch of HTML code. I'm not a programmer, my job is to update to responsive HTML5+CSS3 the markup in a .NET web app made originaly with tables and inline styles (The horror). Dreamweaver CC preferences have options for PHP, Javascript, etc. but not for ASP. Is there a way to work with ASP in Dreamweaver similar to PHP? Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.billymorgan.com/dreamweaverCC.html

Comment: I've seen that page, but there's no "disabled features" folder inside "adobe/adobe dreamweaver cc/configuration", maybe because I'm using Win10 not 7.